# Can't import a Function from a Module ImportError: cannot import name x

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build my own little Module to get to know the Basic steps.
The Structure is like this:

```
/Project
    setup.py
    -----/bin
    -----/blub
    ---------__ init__.py
    ---------blub.py
    -----/docs
    -----/tests
    ---------blub_tests.py
    ---------__ init__.py
```

The Code in blub.py

```
import random

def first():
    print(random.randrange(1,10,1))
```

When I try to import it,

```
from blub import first
```

I get this.
File "< stdin >", line 1, in < module >
Import Error: cannot import name 'first'.

If I name the Function def blub():

```
import random

def blub():
    print(random.randrange(1,10,1))
```

and then:

```
from blub import blub
```

and call it with:
    blub.blub()
everything works fine...

All I could find with Google were Problems with Cyclic Imports or where the chosen Names were the same as some Built-Ins in Python. Unfortunately it did not help...
What am I doing wrong here? 
Thx!

Comment: Try doing a qualified import instead.

Comment: I tried: from blub import first and it does not work. But if I name def blub and call from blub import blub it works fine. Also from .blub import first does not work.